# Cannot reassign XF86Back and XF86Forward keys

Tags: unity, keyboard, thinkpad

I have thinkpad laptop with annoying back/forward keys near the arrow keys. I often press them by mistake, which leads to text losses while typing in browser. In other DEs (mate, xfce etc.) I usually reassigned those keys to switching desktop left/right, and the problem was solved.
But in Unity (tried 14.04 and 15.04) reassigning doesn't work at all :(
Things look correct in Settings - Keyboard Shortcuts (those keys are named Back and Forward there. But desktops aren't switch while browser keeps using them for back/forward actions.

xmodmapping corresponding keys in terminal didn't help either (xev shows the difference though).

Are there any opened bugs (I didnt found any)?
Thanks.